# How to create a custom create route in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I currently have a create method in an invoices controller. However i need another one, which is called 'create_inappointment_invoice'. I was wondering what the syntax was in the routes file to create a route in relation to this. I basically want the same route as this `resources :invoices, controller: "admins/invoices", only: [:create]` but changing the name of the controller action. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`post 'admins/all_invoices', to: 'admin#invoices'`

where admin is your controller and invoices in your action in it.

Comment: thanks for your answer, however i dont quite understand your description.

Comment: If the above route `admins/all_invoices` matches then the control would go to your controller `admin` and action `invoices`
For Eg: 

   `class Admincontroller < ApplicationController
         def invoices
             # write your code  here
         end
      end`

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below snippet should do the job:

```
resources :invoices, controller: "admins/invoices", only: [:create] do
    collection do
        post :create_inappointment_invoice
    end
end
```

OR

```
resources :invoices, controller: "admins/invoices", only: [:create] do
    post :create_inappointment_invoice, on: :collection
end
```

This will hit the `create_inappointment_invoice` method in your `admin/invoices controller`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, this is taking me to the original create method still.

Comment: It shouldn't be! What's the url you are hitting?

Comment: it's currently hitting the `render new` part of my other create action condition, which would suggest that it is still hitting the original create method.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work:

```
    `post "/invoices", to: "admins/invoices#create_inappointment_invoice", as: :create_inappointment_invoice`
```